# Do I really need to register an app to show a simple 'friends' list on my website?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to use the Facebook (Graph) API to show a list of names and pictures of friends of a facebook account (which I own). Do I really need to register my website as an app for this? Since I don't really think of my website as an app... Or can I somehow get an access token that doesn't expire since I can grant access to this list of friends myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of an app on Facebook as an API Key. Your App is how Facebook identifies who is making the call, what permissions you have, and if you are abusing the system or not.

And no, you can't get access to most Graph API data without a valid Facebook App.